# Oct2py binary operator '*' not implemented

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, octave, oct2py

I'm using oct2py to execute an octave function from python, and I get the following error:

> oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error: error: binary operator '*' not
>   implemented for 'int64 scalar' by 'complex matrix' operations

In python, im just calling the function with:

```
from oct2py import octave
results = octave.myOctaveFunction(parameters)
```

In debugging of myOctaveFunction, I think the error is in the code:

```
slc=interpft(slc, OSF*lines, 1);
```

where:

- slc is a complex matrix of size = [241,41] (double precision)
- OSF is an oversampling factor. OSF = 16 (int64)
- lines is the number of rows of slc matrix. lines = 241 (scalar)
- interpft function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpft.html

Edit: detailed traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/ezaqui/Papyrus/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/dynamic.py", line 96, in __call__
    return self._ref().feval(self.name, *inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 369, in feval
    store_as=store_as, plot_dir=plot_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 568, in _feval
    raise Oct2PyError(msg)
Oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error:
error: binary operator '*' not implemented for 'int64 scalar' by 'complex matrix' operations
```

Comment: Your error says you are multiplying a scalar by a complex matrix but, in your description of that line, the only things getting multiplied are two scalars. I would guess either that is not the offending line or `lines` is not actually a scalar.

Comment: I think the multiplication is done inside of interpft function. The code crash exactly before that line

Comment: Do you get a traceback or just the error you posted?

Comment: I've just completed the post with complete traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

```
slc=interpft(slc, double(OSF*lines), 1);
```

---

**Explanation:**

You are trying to multiply a complex matrix with an **int64** type. 
Apparently the multiplication operation is not defined for this type in octave; it's only defined for doubles.

```
>> int64(5) * [1 + 1i]
error: binary operator '*' not implemented for 'int64 scalar' by 'complex scalar' operations

>> double(5) * [1 + 1i]
ans =  5 + 5i
```

So this is not an oct2py problem specifically. Just ensure that `OSF` is converted to `double` before the multiplication with a complex matrix in your octave function instead.

As for *why* you're getting a multiplication with a complex in the first place, I suspect the interpft function takes the result of your multiplication and multiplies a complex matrix somewhere. In octave, as it turns out, multiplying an int64 with a double results in an int64:

```
>> class(int64(5) * double(5))
ans = int64
```